# Closing Webdriver after code in foreach loop is done?

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, google-chrome, webdriver

I have forEach loop that is running some tasks, like register users.  I have tried so far `driver.quit()` and `driver.close()` but they close the web driver before all users are registered. I would like to know if there is any solution to this problem where the web driver should close after the whole process is done.

Comment: Why don't you validate if all the users are getting successfully registered or not. That would inturn allow some buffer time for the other process to complete.

Answer (score 0):

In this case a classic for loop makes sense. First you get the list of all users and its size (the type of List is up to you. I used an ArrayList to demonstrate). Then you create a new List of registered users. Iterate through the users and register them. Once the size of both lists is equal you can quit the driver.

```
List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add("user 1");
    users.add("user 2");
    users.add("user 3");

    List<String> registeredUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

        registeredUsers.add(registerUser(users.get(i)));
        if (users.size() == registeredUsers.size()) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
//Replace with your own code
private String registerUser (String user)
{
    return "registered " + user;
}
```